How to configure Socket.io in nextjs for production?
This is my server.js file
const { createServer } = require('http');
const next = require("next");
const { Server } = require("socket.io");

const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production";
const hostname = "https://quiet-mooncake-8ff89f.netlify.app/";
const port = 3000;
// when using middleware `hostname` and `port` must be provided below
const app = next({ dev , hostname });
const handler = app.getRequestHandler();

app.prepare().then(() => {
  const httpServer = createServer(handler);

  const io = new Server(httpServer);
  /.../

});

This is my Component
"use client";

import { io } from "socket.io-client";

const socket = io();

I have deployed this project and whenever this Component renders it just shows loading and when i tried looking in the network tab in developers tool it shows a pattern of 2 API hitting again and again.
First is https://quiet-mooncake-8ff89f.netlify.app/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OyShAVC
which has Parameters as ->
Request URL:
https://quiet-mooncake-8ff89f.netlify.app/socket.io/?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OyShAVC
Request Method:GET
Status Code:308 Permanent Redirect
Remote Address:[2406:da18:b3d:e202::64]:443
Referrer Policy:strict-origin-when-cross-origin
and Response Parameters as ->
Age:0
Cache-Control:
no-cache
Cache-Status:
"Netlify Edge"; fwd=miss
Content-Type:
text/plain;charset=UTF-8
Date:
Fri, 26 Apr 2024 23:10:28 GMT
Location:
/socket.io?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OyShAVC
Netlify-Vary:
header=x-nextjs-data,cookie=__prerender_bypass|__next_preview_data
Refresh:
0;url=/socket.io?EIO=4&transport=polling&t=OyShAVC
Server:
Netlify
Strict-Transport-Security:
max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains; preload
X-Content-Type-Options:
nosniff
X-Nf-Request-Id:
01HWEASA1Y24RXM1J3Z4W6W5MQ
And the other one is is just redirecting to 404 page not found
Please tell me what should i do..
I have tried chnaging the hardcoding the URL in my code but it is still nopt working
